# Socket.io 1.0, IE7. cannot read emitted messages

Tags: node.js, socket.io, internet-explorer-7

Trying to read emitted message from the server. IE7 seems to failed..

**The server code:**

The server will emit "news" every half second, and disconnect after 20 news is emitted

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server,{
            'transports':[
                'polling',
                'websocket',
                'flashsocket',
                'htmlfile'
            ]
         });


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connect: '+socket.id);
    var num = 0;

    var cInterval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log(num+' emit news');
        socket.emit('news', 'this is news '+num);
        num++;
        if(num==20) socket.disconnect();
    },500);

    socket.on('disconnect', function(why){ 
        console.log('disconnect: '+socket.id);
        clearInterval(cInterval);
    });

});

server.listen(port,ip);
console.log('io ready');
```

**The Client Code:**

The client will log connection attempt, news content, and disconnect event.

```
var socket = io('ws://localhost:8080')
.on('connect',function(){
    logging('connecting');
})
.on('disconnect',function(){
    logging('disconnected');
})
.on('news', function (data) {
    logging(data);
});
```

I am not using `console.log` as a logging mechanism so IE7 should be OK.

**result in IE8,IE9, Chrome:**

```
connecting
this is news 0
this is news 1
...
this is news 19
disconnected
```

**result in IE7:**

```
connecting
disconnected
```

Is this known?

are there any workaround(s)?

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks..

Comment: using JSON2 works, IE7 doesn't have a JSON object

Answer (score 2):

use JSON2 as IE7 doesn't have a native JSON object.
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min.js

Comment: looks like i'm talking to myself... ** :|